# Object member variables not getting serialized

Tags: java, jersey, jackson2

I have a class `Test` which has a member variable of type `NestedTest`.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonView;

class Test{

    String s1;

    @JsonView(ConvertView.class)
    int a;

    @JsonView(ConvertView.class)
    NestedTest nestedObj;
}
```

```
class NestedTest{
    int n;
    String s;
}
```

After serializing an object of class Test, the field nestedObj is showing to be null. I am guessing this is because I have disabled default view inclusion which is being applied on fields of NestedTest object as well. If this is the case, how do I prevent it? I want to disable inclusion of fields which doesn't have a view attached to them only for the outer class and not the fields of Object member variables.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MapperFeature;
.........
.........
Test test =new Test();
........
........
ObjectWriter writer = new ObjectMapper().disable(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION).writer();
String s= writer.withView(ConvertView.class).writeValueAsString(test);
System.out.println(s);
```

My pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Inheritance</groupId>
    <artifactId>Inheritance</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the `@JsonView` on class level for the `NestedTest`:

```java
@JsonView(ConvertView.class)
class NestedTest{
    int n;
    String s;
}
```

For your custom classes you need to specify the `@JsonView` for every class in the tree, which fields you want to make visible, to the view.

Comment: I was trying to do that but it was throwing an error. Later figured that I was using an older version of Jackson. Updated that, now works like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: Did my answer help you in the end?